# Plot and Subplot

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I have a large for loop that produces a lot of graphs. I'm adding functionality to the code and would like to have the option to toggle between putting a series of graphs into a one figure with subplots, or plotting the graphs as individual figures. I tried to do this using the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
 figure
 if (SubplotOPT == 0)
  subplot(2,2,1);
 end
```

The idea is that if the SubplotOPT == 0 is not satisfied then the code will produce a individual figure, however, I think matlab is making a subplot regardless of the if statement.

Comment: but not work, can you elaborate?  What happens instead?  It sounds like you see a "subplotted" figure when you don't expect it.  Also, can you give a little more background in the code, before and after?

Comment: I figured it out just a minute ago. The code above produces a subplot of the position indepedent of the loop.                                                           figure
 if (SubplotOPT == 0)
  subplot(2,2,1);   else                                                                  subplot(1,1,1)                                                              end

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for i=1:3
figure(i)   
    if i==3
        subplot(2,1,1)
           plot(rand(1,100))
    else
           plot(rand(1,100))
    end
end
```

here a regular figure is created in the loop, where only for a specific condition a subplot figure is created.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't happy with either of the two previous solutions, so here is my go at it:

```
% Should we add a subplot, or create a new figure & axes 
if (SubplotOpt == 0)
  ax = subplot(2,1,1);
else
  f = figure;
  ax = axes();
end

plot( 0:.01:2*pi, sin(0:.01:2*pi), 'Parent', ax);
```

Basically I've abstracted away the subplot/figure code from the plotting code, it makes it easier to read and edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (SubplotOPT == 0)
    subplot(2,2,1);
else
    subplot(1,1,1);
end
```

Comment: not need to write `subplot(1,1,1)` in that code. a simple `plot` should do... unless you rewrite the same figure and not clearing it...